# How can I use the event @select to select some text from a paragraph in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js with **Nuxt** in SSR, I would like when I highlight some text to get this text and perform an action on it.

I found a way to do that with some text in `<input>` but I would like here to be able to @select some text from a paragraph and not from an input.

here is how I did using `<input>`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input @select="testFunction2()" value="TEXTE TO SELECT">
  </div>
</template> 

mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('select',this.testFunction2,innerHTML)  
},
methods:{
  testFunction2(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value.substring(event.target.selectionStart, event.target.selectionEnd));
  },
```

I tried to replace in the 'listener' code, the 'value' by 'innerHTML', but it doesn't seem to work,

Thank you!

EDIT : 
I used the method proposed by Terry and it's working well on a paragraphe.
But when I want to highlight some text on an object that I return from a database in a v-loop on the Vue component I get this error : 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLDocument.'

This is the object I return on my vue component, the object is actually a html text that i convert to a plain text with v-html :

```
<li   v-for=" itemJournal in journalContent"> 
 <b-row>
<b-col col lg="10" id="myNoteList" class="htmlNonUser grey-text text- 
darken-2 myNoteList" style=""><p v-html="itemJournal.content" 
ref="target"> </p> 
</b-col>
</b-row>


  mounted:function(){
     document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
    if (event.target === this.$refs.target || 
  event.target.contains(this.$refs.target))
    this.testFunction1();
  });
  },

  testFunction1(event){

console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
 },
```

Comment: The `this.$refs.target` is just an example in my code. In your case the `target` is not unique, so it makes no sense to compare against it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `select` event is only supported by input-like elements. If you want to get the selected text within regular elements, simply listen to the `mouseup` event. The mouseup event should call a function where you simply call `window.getSelection().toString()` to retrieve the selected text.

In the example below, we bind the `mouseup` listener to the `document`, and perform additional filtering within the event handler so that only an element of interest (in this case, `this.$refs.target`) will trigger the callback that gets the selection:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
      if (event.target === this.$refs.target || event.target.contains(this.$refs.target))
        this.testFunction();
    });
  },
  methods: {
    testFunction() {
      console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input @select="testFunction" value="Text to select" />
  <p ref="target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

**Update**: Based on your answer, you will either want to update what the `event.target` is compared against (e.g. if you don't want any selection to trigger `testFunction()`), or leave the `if` conditional out completely:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
    this.testFunction1();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's what im looking for, its working on <p>, i actually wanted to make it happen on an object that I return from a database in a v-for loop on the template component. When I apply that on this object I get : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>. Do you have any idea why is this happening ..? I added more details in an Edit on my Post. thank you

Comment: @romain1304 That's because the `this.$refs.target` is not defined in your code. What you want instead is replace that with the element that you want to allow selection from. If not, you can leave that entire `if` statement out

Comment: Yes I actually just found that out ,,, thanks a lot!

Comment: @romain1304 Accept his answer if it's solved your issue (and upvote it if you want)

Answer (score 3):

I'm unclear on whether you want to react to a selection inside the input or elsewhere in the document. Assuming inside the input:

- Listen to `mouseup` event.
- Pass the event itself with `$event`.
- `getSelection()` doesn't work on input values, so use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` to get the selection.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    logSelectionWithinInput(e) {
      var selection = e.target.value.substring(
        e.target.selectionStart,
        e.target.selectionEnd
      );
      console.log(selection);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input @mouseup="logSelectionWithinInput($event)" value="Text to select" />
</div>
```